Intune Conditional Access claim challenge testing
I'm currently trying to add the possibility to challenge claims that are thrown by a CA policy.
This is simply done with some C# code from the MSAL .NET library
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/advanced/exceptions/msal-error-handling#conditional-access-and-claims-challenges
From my what I have tried the only way I seem to be able to trigger a CA claim challenge is by having the device managed. For Android this means using the company portal and setting up a work profile.
However I want to test the code first before pushing it into production. I was wondering does anyone have experience with how to CA claim challenges locally/in debug mode?
I have already tried using MFA, but it doesn't seem to trigger the required claim challenge.
Code is shown here, in case it helps
 try
 {
        
        bool useEmbbedView = ServiceLocator.Default.GetService<IDeviceInfo>().DevicePlatform == PlatformType.Windows ? true : !_publicClientApp.IsSystemWebViewAvailable;
        _tokenInteractiveParameterBuilder = _publicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(_azureResources.Scopes)
                                                            .WithPrompt(Prompt.ForceLogin)                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                            .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(useEmbbedView);  
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginHint))
        {
            _tokenInteractiveParameterBuilder = _loggedInAccount == null
                ? _tokenInteractiveParameterBuilder.WithLoginHint(loginHint)
                : _tokenInteractiveParameterBuilder.WithAccount(_loggedInAccount);
        }
    
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await _tokenInteractiveParameterBuilder.ExecuteAsync();
        return AuthenticationState.CreateAzureAuthenticationState(authenticationResult, AuthenticationStateResult.Success);
}
catch(MsalServiceException msalServiceException) when (msalServiceException.Claims != null)
{                   
    // Handle the claims challenge
    string claimsChallenge = msalServiceException.Claims;

    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await _tokenInteractiveParameterBuilder.WithClaims(claimsChallenge).ExecuteAsync();
    return AuthenticationState.CreateAzureAuthenticationState(authenticationResult, AuthenticationStateResult.Success);
}


A proper debugging option doesn't seem to be available. So I did the next best thing available.

Change the package name
Create a release build of my local code with a different
Sign it "manually" using bundetool
Upload it as a Private app to the managed google play store

I can now test my local build.
